# Run-time error '1004': The PivotTable field name is not valid

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating an 8th Pivot Table in the same spreadsheet and I am getting the following error for the LAST PIVOT TABLE:

**"Run-time error '1004':
The PivotTable field name is not valid. To create a PivotTable report you must use data that is organized as a list of labeled columns. If you are changing the name of a PivotTable field, you must type a new name for the field.
"**

However, I have tried to change the name of Pivot Table several times and the issue has not been resolved.

My code is as follows:

```
Sub Macro1()
'Pivot Table 8
'Declare Variables
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As String
Dim LastCol As String
Dim SData As String
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable

Set PSheet = Worksheets("US MASTER")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("US Master Macro")

LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
SData = "'US Master Macro'!R1C1:R" & LastRow & "C" & LastCol

Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=SData)

Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=Worksheets("US MASTER").Range("Y4"), TableName:="InfoView Cases")

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("InfoView Cases")
 .SmallGrid = False
 'Add Days to Row Field
 With .PivotFields("Age of Case")
 .Orientation = xlRowField
 .Position = 1
 End With
 'Add PR ID to Values Field
 With .PivotFields("PR ID")
 .Orientation = xlDataField
 .Function = xlCount
 .Position = 1
 End With
 'Add Filter
 With .PivotFields("SAP Notification")
 .Orientation = xlPageField
 .Position = 1
 End With
 'Add Filter
 With .PivotFields("Case Status")
 .Orientation = xlPageField
 .Position = 2
 End With
End With

'Deselect Filter

    l = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("InfoView Cases").PivotFields("SAP Notification"). _
        PivotItems.Count - 1

    For k = 1 To l
        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("InfoView Cases").PivotFields("SAP Notification")
            .PivotItems(k).Visible = False
        End With
    Next k

        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("InfoView Cases").PivotFields("SAP Notification")
            .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = True
        End With

'Deselect Filter

    n = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("InfoView Cases").PivotFields("Case Status"). _
        PivotItems.Count - 1

    For m = 1 To n
        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("InfoView Cases").PivotFields("Case Status")
            .PivotItems(m).Visible = False
        End With
    Next m

        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("InfoView Cases").PivotFields("Case Status")
            .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = True
        End With


'Add InfoView Cases
PSheet.Range("Y3").Value = "InfoView Cases"
PSheet.Range("Y4").Value = "Days"
'Merge
PSheet.Range("Y3:Z3").Merge

'Sort Pivot Table
    Range("Y5:Y100").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("InfoView Cases").PivotFields("Age of Case").AutoSort _
        xlAscending, "Age of Case"


End Sub
```

My code breaks in the line

```
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=Worksheets("US MASTER").Range("Y4"), TableName:="InfoView Cases")
```

Comment: @QHarr will do! Your answer did fix the issue but the code was not provided... I will vote for your answer but also will provide the code as well. Thank you for reminding me!

Comment: What does the top couple rows of your data (that creates your pivot cache) look like? The error says "PivotTable field name is not valid", which implies to me that one of the items in the first (header) row is probably a number or some other invalid value to be used as a field name.

Comment: @PeterT Its a table with the first row as the header and the rest of the rows as the actual values for the table. None of the headers is a number.

Comment: Make the `SData` range a table. The data source is rows & columns anyway; an actual *named table* ("format as table" from the home ribbon) is *always* a valid pivot table data source - watch how Excel fixes whatever heading is wrong as you convert the range to a table.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon The source data is a formatted table. The code works perfectly for the first 7 Pivot Tables and ignores the 8th one-The one that I put the code for above.

Comment: Per your code the source data is a string with a hard-coded sheet name and range address, not a `ListObject.DataBodyRange` which wouldn't need code changes when the number of rows/columns changes.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Is it possible for you to submit the code for it? Thank you!!

Comment: `Dim srcTable As ListObject`; `Set srcTable = DSheet.ListObjects("name of the table")`; `Dim srcRange As Range`; `Set srcRange = srcTable.Range`; then use `srcRange` as a source.

Comment: One thing that is not obvious from your code or description is if you're using the same data range for all eight pivot tables. If so, then you can reuse the same pivot cache for all pivot tables and save that step (and memory).

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I dont know the name of my table. How can I figure that out?

Comment: @PeterT I tried to store the pivot cache and it doesnt work. My PTable [Pivot Table "InfoView Cases"] seems to be = Nothing.

Comment: If there's only 1 table then index `1` will do. Otherwise you can see it near the top-left corner of Excel when you're in it, under the dynamic "Table Tools" ribbon tab.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon your answer worked! Thank you! Can you make your answer in an answer format so I can vote for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was provided by Mathieu Guindon:

```
Dim srcRange As Range
sTable = "DataTable"
   Set ListObj = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, [A1].CurrentRegion, , xlYes)
   ListObj.Name = sTable 'The name for the table
   ListObj.TableStyle = "TableStyleDark8"
Dim srcRange_s As String
 srcRange_s = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DataTable")

'Pivot Table 8
'Pivot Table 8
'Pivot Table 8

'Define Pivot Cache and Insert Pivot Table
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=srcRange_s)

Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(Range("Y4"), TableName:="InfoView Cases")
'Add Fields
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("InfoView Cases")
 .SmallGrid = False
 'Add Days to Row Field
 With .PivotFields("Age of Case")
 .Orientation = xlRowField
 .Position = 1
 End With
 'Add PR ID to Values Field
 With .PivotFields("PR ID")
 .Orientation = xlDataField
 .Function = xlCount
 .Position = 1
 End With
 'Add Filter
 With .PivotFields("SAP Notification")
 .Orientation = xlPageField
 .Position = 1
 End With
```