# Creating pivot table: Error - The pivottable field name is not valid

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I am trying to create a pivot table based on a set range via VBA.

I have defined my variables.

```
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim PField As PivotField

'Declare Variables
Set PSheet = Worksheets("TS")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Data Entry")

'Define Data Range
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

PSheet.PivotTables("Timesheet").TableRange2.Clear

'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)

'Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(5, 1), TableName:="Timesheet")
```

I get an error at insert pivot table code.

> Run time error 1004:
>   The pivottable field name is not valid. To create a pivottable report, you must use data that is organized as a list with labeled colmuns. if you are changing the name of a pivotable field, you must type a new name for the field.

My data range is in DSheet from range A1:P50. Range will not change in the future.

Comment: Last line - Insert Blank Pivot Table

Comment: Does Row 1 of DSheet contain column headings?

Comment: Yes, it does have a header in row 1

Comment: Does the table already exist? `PSheet.PivotTables("Timesheet").TableRange2.Clear`

Comment: It does not exist right now but it will and it will need to be deleted before inserting new table in PSheet. While running the code for the first time I do delete this line to ensure it does not give me an error.

Comment: Just to add that pivot table source is a Table whose range is A1:P50 and first row is the row headings. Not sure if this makes any difference.

Comment: One of your headers isn't a valid name. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50726893/run-time-error-1004-the-pivottable-field-name-is-not-valid). Can you post a pic of your header row?

Comment: Badge Number 
Position
Employee Name
PO NumberBillable / Non Billable Billable Shift / Non Billable Reason Date Hours CostCenter ReasonCode Work Order DelayCode Activity Code Sub Activity Work Order or Cost Centre Comments

Comment: I copied your code into a new Sub in a standard module and it ran without error (other than needing to skip the line the deletes the old one).

Comment: Resolved. I set table as list object and set table in Dsheet.listobjects. Below link did help to get the resolution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50726893/run-time-error-1004-the-pivottable-field-name-is-not-valid

Comment: Post the resolution as an answer instead of a comment!